# when I am trying to upload image on imgbb from my react app by fetch I am getting this error "error : {message: 'Empty upload source.', code: 130}"

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I am Building a React App. For My Image Upload I Want To Use **IMGBB** .But When I Try To Upload Image **BY FETCH I AM GETTING ERROR WITH BAD REQUEST**.So How Can I Solve This Issue?

**MY CODE-**

```
const formData=new FormData();
        formData.append("file",e.target.files[0]);
        console.log(formData);
        const url=`https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload?key=MY_KEY`;
        fetch(url,{
            method: 'post',
            headers:{"content-type": "multipart/form-data"},
            body:formData
        })
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(data=>console.log(data));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
formData.append("image", e.target.files[0]);
```

Because Image bb is not accepting any name without 'image'.